# How to handle a form with multiple levels of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following model hierarchy:

```
User
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :locations
```

So I have a form that has the following elements:

1. username
2. company name
3. 3 drop down lists for the company location

I am not sure how I can create the user, and then also create the company and also associate the locations to that company.

Comment: are you using simple_form gem? if yes you can use https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon cocoon gem which should handle your case

Answer (score 0):

if you use simple_form gem and with cocoon gem you need have something like below. This will help you add locations and set the company for a user

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
    = f.input :username
    = f.input :company, collection: @companies
    %h3 Locations
    #locations
      = f.simple_fields_for :locations do |location|
        = render 'location_fields', f: location
      .links
        = link_to_add_association 'add location', f, :locations
    = f.submit
```

Here location_fields is another partial. You need to have a partial _location_fields

```
SimpleForm: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form
Cocoon: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon
```